# What is the approach to determine the exact click coordinates within an iframe relative to the root document's window in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, onclick, mouse-coordinates

A Chrome extension I'm developing injects a content script into the active tab, including all frames on the page using allFrames: true. In the content script, an event listener detects click events in the DOM and retrieves the coordinates (x and y) of the click. Whenever I click inside a nested iframe within the page, the coordinates I obtain are relative to the iframe window rather than the main browser window. The click coordinates must, however, be relative to the browser window, regardless of whether the click occurs within an iframe or the root document.

To retrieve the click coordinates directly, I initially used event.clientX and event.clientY. Unfortunately, this only provides me with coordinates for the iframe, not the main browser window.

I attempted to traverse the iframe hierarchy using window.parent within the content script to access the parent window and calculate the relative coordinates. Unfortunately, this approach didn't work as expected, as I couldn't find a reliable way to establish the correct positioning. Similarly accessing the parent element's DOM gives CORS, so this method is not reliable either.

I understand that iframe boundaries can complicate coordinate calculations. I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve consistent click coordinates relative to the browser window, regardless of the nested iframe's presence.

Any help or suggestions on how to calculate the click coordinates inside a nested iframe relative to the browser window within a Chrome extension would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To traverse the hierarchy correctly you need to use [parent.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and not direct DOM access. When the `parent` content script receives the message it'll enumerate all iframes in its DOM and compare each iframe's contentWindow to `event.source` to find the frame that sent this message. Note that you may need to traverse inside shadowRoot and maybe even use chrome.dom.openOrClosedShadowRoot

Comment: It might be simpler to use `event.screenX` and subtract the top document's `window.screenX`, same for `Y`. To get the top doc's data you can use messaging. To adjust for the toolbar height you'd need to get any mouse event in the top doc and subtract screenX from clientX, same for Y.